# Strange issue with DDXMLElement

Tags: swift, xmppframework

I'm using XMPPFramework and just updated to the version 3.7 and now when I try to compile this line:

```
body.setStringValue(message)
```

it gives me this error:

```
Value of type 'DDXMLElement' has no member 'setStringValue'
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
body.stringValue = message
```

as `body.setStringValue` is not available in `swift3`